# do-release-upgrade from 20.10 to 21.04 on Raspi not working?

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I get a message that no new versions are available.

Any idea, why this happens?

Comment: I think some time needs to pass before you can upgrade - but I don't remember how long.

Comment: Don't `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` offer you upgrade to 21.04 still ?

Comment: though the issue I talk about in the duplicate doesn't apply to armv7/arm64 nor other architectures... the evaluation assesses all architectures so they remain somewhat in sync (you can look at the status page to view the watched & blocker bugs if you wish on discourse)

Comment: i wouldn't upgrade from 20.10 to 21.04 as I have already had a bricked instance - tried again yesterday and all i get is the load screen with the ubuntu logo at the bottom and then nothing... not reachable by ping etc.       Note: fresh installs also do not work either

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be able to download it once it appears on the following list: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release

Otherwise, one needs a manual installation.

Comment: "sudo do-release-upgrade -d" should do the trick until then.

Comment: Yes, that's true; however, it is not recommended.